# How can I extract the redundancy in this Factor word definition with dataflow combinators?

Tags: combinators, factor-lang

I'm using the early ProjectEuler problems as a way to get to know Factor. Already in the [very first problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) I don't find a satisfactory solution.

I can solve the division test with this

```
: 3or5divisible ( n -- ? ) [ 3 mod ] [ 5 mod ] bi * 0 = ;
```

But what I don't like is the repetition of the `mod`. Of course it's only two times, but another problem might need to check 200.

I tried with [`map`](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-map,sequences.html), [`curry`](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-curry,kernel.html), [`bi`](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-bi%2Ckernel.html), [`2bi`](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-2bi%2Ckernel.html), [`bi@`](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-bi__at__,kernel.html), arrays and plain stack values etc. I always get a stack underflow or an effect mismatch (when using `map`). I have have not yet found a way to see the results of my trials in the inspector.

How can I factor that `mod` out and have it applied to `{ 3 5 }` or an equivalent stack?
Cool would be two variants e.g. of a `mod3and5` (including effect specification); one that leaves `2 1` on the stack for input 11 and one that returns `{ 2 1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of doing it this way, which removes one of the mods, but ends up adding a `bi-curry@` function.

```
: 3or5divisible ( n -- ? ) 3 5 [ mod ] bi-curry@ bi * 0 = ;
```